# Authorization for Google Content API for Shopping

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-client, oauth-2.0, google-api-python-client

I'm using `google-api-python-client` library to work with Google Content Api for shopping.
I'm trying to build script, that would every 24 hours pull data from Content API for Shopping and update some tables on own server.

But I faced up with auth problem. 
I moved through steps in guide, created client id, and even recieved refresh token via `--noauth_local_webserver` option.

But this token became invalid in few hours and require client to interact with app again.

I have same script, but for Google Adwords Api. In that case my refresh_token lives much longer, as for now - few months.

Can you please point me, where I'm doing something wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [OAuth Service Account authorization](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/how-tos/service-accounts).

This is server-to-server authorization, so no human interaction is needed after Refresh Token has expired.